# How to define even permutations correctly?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

I define even permutations as following, but there may be some error. I use it in two different way and get different output.

```
evenper[x_] := Select[Permutations[x], Signature[#] == 1 &]
```

Way 1:

```
evenper[x_] := Select[Permutations[x], Signature[#] == 1 &]
manual=evenper[{a, b, c, d}]
phi = 1.61803398875;
p1 = manual /. {a -> phi, b -> 1, c -> 1/phi, d -> 0};
p2 = manual /. {a -> phi, b -> 1, c -> -1/phi, d -> 0};
p3 = manual /. {a -> phi, b -> -1, c -> 1/phi, d -> 0};
p4 = manual /. {a -> phi, b -> -1, c -> -1/phi, d -> 0};
p5 = manual /. {a -> -phi, b -> 1, c -> 1/phi, d -> 0};
p6 = manual /. {a -> -phi, b -> 1, c -> -1/phi, d -> 0};
p7 = manual /. {a -> -phi, b -> -1, c -> 1/phi, d -> 0};
p8 = manual /. {a -> -phi, b -> -1, c -> -1/phi, d -> 0};
list1=Union[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8]//Sort;
```

This result is what I want.

Way 2:

```
evenper[x_] := Select[Permutations[x], Signature[#] == 1 &]

phi = 1.61803398875;
list20 = #*{phi, 1, 1/phi, 0} & /@ (Tuples[{{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1}}]);
list2 = Flatten[evenper[#] & /@ list20, 1] // Sort;
```

But you will find `list1 != list2` as following

```
Position[list1, {-1.618033988749895`, 0, 0.6180339887498948`, -1}]
Position[list2, {-1.618033988749895`, 0, 0.6180339887498948`, -1}]
(*{}*)
(*{{6}}*)
```

Comment: Would you attempt to give a more minimal example of the updated problem?  That is a lot of code to read through with the care needed for debugging.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hi, the problem is updated. The error lies in the definition of `evenper`, but I do not know why.

Comment: A more accurate value for `phi` is `phi = GoldenRatio//N;` Also , it is unnecessary to use `Sort` in the definition of `list1` since `Union` already sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your Question.  With the new, clearer example I believe I can see the issue.

### Analysis

The first method uses `evenper` on Symbolic values that are in canonical order:

```
r1 = evenper[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {a, d, b, c}, {b, a, d, c}, {b, c, a, d}, {b, d, c, a},
>  {c, a, b, d}, {c, b, d, a}, {c, d, a, b}, {d, a, c, b}, {d, b, a, c}, {d, c, b, a}}
> ```

Recalling the definition of [`Signature`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Signature.html)

> `Signature[list]`
>       gives the signature of the permutation needed to place the elements of `list` in canonical order.

We cannot therefore expect the same permutations to be selected if `evenper` is used on on elements that are not in canonical order:

```
rls = {a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 3, d -> 4};
r2 = evenper[{a, b, c, d} /. rls]
r2 /. Reverse[rls, 2]
% === r1
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 3},
>  {3, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
>
> {{a, b, d, c}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, d, c, b}, {b, a, c, d}, {b, c, d, a}, {b, d, a, c},
>  {c, a, d, b}, {c, b, a, d}, {c, d, b, a}, {d, a, b, c}, {d, b, c, a}, {d, c, a, b}}
>
> False
> ```

### Solution

If you wish to apply a certain set of permutations to arbitrary expressions, regardless of their canonical ordering, you can first permute a list of indices (natural numbers) and then use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) to extract them from the expression list:

```
Select[Permutations @ Range @ 3, Signature[#] == 1 &]
{z, a, p}[[#]] & /@ %
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}}
>
> {{z, a, p}, {a, p, z}, {p, z, a}}
> ```

Applied to your problem:

```
perms = Select[Permutations @ Range @ 4, Signature[#] == 1 &];

phi = 1.61803398875;

tup = # {phi, 1, 1/phi, 0} & /@ Tuples[{1, -1}, 4];

result = Union @@ Outer[Part, tup, perms, 1];

result == list1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

As [rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/) informed me in a comment a greatly improved method for *Mathematica* 8 or later is to use [`AlternatingGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlternatingGroup.html) and [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) as follows:

```
fn = # ~Permute~ AlternatingGroup[Length @ #] &;

fn @ {z, a, p}
```

> ```
> {{z, a, p}, {a, p, z}, {p, z, a}}
> ```

```
perms === fn @ Range @ 4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: For your toolbag - proper (and much more efficient for non-trivial sizes) is:`Permute[#,AlternatingGroup@Length@#]&`...

Comment: @ciao Thanks!  I'll amend my answer.  I am grateful that you continue to contribute even in nontraditional ways. :-)

Comment: Ah, I now understand what OP will be using this for; s/he is trying to generate vertices of polychorons… the stuff with the golden ratio makes me think of the [600-cell](http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/600-cell).

Answer (score 5):

The sorting (ordering) done by Union is different for different forms of expressions, e.g., analytic versus numeric expressions for a number.

```
Union[{2., (Sqrt[5] + 1)/2}]
```

> {2., 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}

```
% // N
```

> {2., 1.61803}

```
Union[{2., (Sqrt[5] + 1.0)/2}]
```

> {1.61803, 2.}

```
SortBy[{2., (Sqrt[5] + 1)/2}, N]
```

> {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), 2.}