# How to get "Signature" of each element of "Permutation" output

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, functional-style, permutation

I need to sum over all possible permutations, multiplied by the `Signature` of each permutation of a **given list of symbols**.  But, I don't know how to determine the `Signature` of each particular permutation **with respect to the original given list** (because the original `input` list may not be in canonical order).

Here's my code that does the job *without* including the appropriate minus signs:

```
input = {b, a, c};
Total[Map[(*signature factor here*)function[#] &, Permutations[input]]]

(*function[{a, b, c}] + function[{a, c, b}] + function[{b, a, c}] + 
  function[{b, c, a}] + function[{c, a, b}] + function[{c, b, a}]*)
```

---

1. How do I include the appropriate minus sign?  For `input={b, a, c}` The output should be:

   ```
   (* -function[{a, b, c}] + function[{a, c, b}] + function[{b, a, c}] - 
     function[{b, c, a}] - function[{c, a, b}] + function[{c, b, a}]*)
   ```

   For `input={a, b, c}` , the output should be

   ```
   (* function[{a, b, c}] - function[{a, c, b}] - function[{b, a, c}] + 
     function[{b, c, a}] + function[{c, a, b}] - function[{c, b, a}]*)
   ```
2. Also, since `input` may be large, is it possible to get the signature during runtime (of `Permutations`) for higher performance?

Comment: Closely related: [(60111)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60111/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry it took a while; I wanted to be fair about which answer I found to be most useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the method I described in: [How to define even permutations correctly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60111/how-to-define-even-permutations-correctly/60200#60200):

```
fW[a_List] :=
  With[{p = Permutations @ Range @ Length @ a},
    Dot[Signature /@ p, func /@ Extract[a, p ~Partition~ 1]]
  ]
```

This is faster than both of kguler's functions (which are in turn faster than belisarius's code):

```
f1 = Function[{k}, Total[Map[Signature[ #[[Ordering @ k]] ] func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];
f2 = Function[{k}, Total[Map[Signature[#] Signature[k] func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];

(res1 = f1 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First

(res2 = f2 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First

(resW = fW /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First

Equal @@ {res1, res2, resW}
```

> ```
> 2.290631
>
> 2.320133
>
> 1.121564
>
> True
> ```

---

**Note:** my code uses an [undocumented syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64231/121) for `Extract` which works in *Mathematica* 8 or later.  If you have an earlier version please use:

```
fW[a_List] :=
  With[{p = Permutations @ Range @ Length @ a},
    Dot[Signature /@ p, func /@ (a[[#]] & /@ p)]
  ]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
input = {b, a, c};
```

Perhaps

```
Total[Map[Signature[ #[[Ordering @ input]] ] func[#] &, Permutations[input]]]
(* -func[{a, b, c}] + func[{a, c, b}] + func[{b, a, c}] - 
    func[{b, c, a}] - func[{c, a, b}] + func[{c, b, a}] *)
```

or

```
Total[Map[Signature[#]Signature[input] func[#] &, Permutations[input]]]
(* same result *)
```

or

```
Signature[input] Total[Map[Signature[#] func[#] &, Permutations[input]]]
(* same result *)

Function[{k}, {Row@k, Total[Map[Signature[ #[[Ordering @ k]] ] func[#] &,
      Permutations[k]]]}] /@ Permutations[{a, b, c}] // TableForm
```

> [image]

Timing comparisons:

```
f1 = Function[{k},Total[Map[Signature[ #[[Ordering @ k]] ] func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];
f2 = Function[{k},Total[Map[Signature[#] Signature[k] func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];
f3 = Function[{k},Signature[k] Total[Map[Signature[#]  func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];
fB = Function[{k},Total[Map[Signature[# /. mapping[k]] func[#] &, Permutations[k]]]];
fW[a_List] := With[{p = Permutations @ Range @ Length @ a},
              Dot[Signature /@ p, func /@ Extract[a, p ~Partition~ 1]] ];
```

All permutations of length 5 and 6:

```
(res1 = f1 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}] ); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.062501 *)
(res2 = f2 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}] ); //AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.061893 *)
(res3 = f3 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}] ); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(resB = fB /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}] ); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.171893 *)
(resW = fW /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}] ); // AbsoluteTiming // First
Equal @@ {res1, res2, res3, resB, resW}
(* True *)

(res1 = f1 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.245413 *)
(res2 = f2 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.410684 *)
(res3 = f3 /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.674195 *)
(resB = fB /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 7.132036 *)
(resW = fW /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, x}]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.101775 *)
Equal @@ {res1, res2, res3, resB, resW}
(* True *)
```

Random permutations of length 9 and 10:

```
rp = PermutationList[RandomPermutation[9], 9];
(res1 = f1@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.332165 *)
(res2 = f2@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.111594 *)
(res3 = f3@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.024557 *)
(resB = fB@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 7.328174 *)
(resW = fW@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 2.007417 *)
Equal @@ {res1, res2, res3, resB, resW}
(*True*)

rp = PermutationList[RandomPermutation[10], 10];
(res1 = f1@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 24.681737 *)
(res2 = f2@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 22.776874 *)
(res3 = f3@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 20.031120 *)
(resB = fB@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 78.861839 *)
(resW = fW@rp); // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 21.637332 *)
Equal @@ {res1, res2, res3, resB, resW}
(*True*)
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to clarify that input is an arbitrary list of symbols.  Thus, I can't hard-code the minus sign.  *e.g* If `input={a,b,c}` then the sign in front of `f[{a,b,c}]` should be `+1` (I have edited the question to clarify this).

Comment: @QuantumDot, could you please check if the updated post works as you expect?

Comment: Yes this works very nicely!  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I slightly modified your code formatting in the interest of readability.  I hope you approve.

Answer (score 3):

```
mapping[set_] := Dispatch@Thread[set -> Range@Length@set]
input = {a, b, c};
Total[Map[Signature[# /. mapping[input]] function[#] &, Permutations[input]]]

(* function[{a, b, c}] - function[{a, c, b}] - function[{b, a, c}] + 
   function[{b, c, a}] + function[{c, a, b}] - function[{c, b, a}]*)
```