# In which version was this Extract syntax introduced?

Tags: functions, undocumented, compatibility

In *Mathematica* 10.0.1 this works:

```
Extract[{a, b, c, d, e}, {{{1, 3}}, {{5, 4}}, {{2}}}]
```

> ```
> {{a, c}, {e, d}, {b}}
> ```

In *Mathematica* 7.0.1 it does not.  In which version was this syntax introduced?

Comment: Works on V9.0.1

Comment: Also on v8.0.0.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Since I am not aware of any release between 7.0.1 and 8.0.0 I think I have my answer.  Would you consider posting that as such?  I think this could be a useful reference for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Mma v.8.0.0 here and it works and gives the same result as v10.

Just as a reference, it works also on v9.0.1.

IDK if there are versions between 7.0.1 and 8.0.0, though.

Comment: The [revision history](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) says that there are no public versions between 7.0.1 and 8.0.0 so I am accepting this.